# npm publishing same version won't update dependencies from in package.json

Tags: npm, nexus, package.json

For some reason I can't remove dependencies from my published npm package without changing the version.

When i first published it, package.json had some dependencies like:

```
"version": "1.0.0",
"author": {
  "name": "me"
},
"dependencies": {
  "@angular/common": "^4.2.0",
  "@angular/core": "^4.2.0",
}
```

Later I removed the dependencies, changed the author and republished, what I get when I install the package is:

```
"version": "1.0.0",    
"author": {
  "name": "me-changed"
},
"dependencies": {
  "@angular/common": "^4.2.0",
  "@angular/core": "^4.2.0",
}
```

I'm using Nexus 2.14 as repository manager and NPM 3.10.
Is this a wanted feature? If not, what is causing it?

Answer (score 2):

You can't change your package and publish it without updating the version. If you published one version it is fix and can't be changed afterwards.

Comment: That's what happens now with public npm repository, earlier in npm history you had the option to --force a publish and keep the same version. this option remained on Nexus repositories.

Comment: Okay, but overall this is a bad behavior because you can't be sure that you will get the same code after installing the package next time. Why speaks against bumping the version?

Comment: I wanted to keep the same versioning method as my company does for maven artifacts, so i'd prefer to not bump version on every single bug fix or typo etc.

Comment: That is not how version work and will led to irreproducible builds. Please check out http://semver.org/.

Comment: @floriangosse is right. if you don't want to bump the version for a change, you don't need versioning. Even if it's a small change.

Comment: @floriangosse is very right. To cite rule 3 http://semver.org/#spec-item-3 from server which is used by npm `Once a versioned package has been released, the contents of that version MUST NOT be modified. Any modifications MUST be released as a new version.` Therefor bumping your versionnumber is NOT OPTIONAL.